# Problema al realizar un bucle

Tags: bucle-for, while, pseint, pseudocódigo

estoy haciendo un programa simple donde se introduce y muestra el nombre y el sexo de una persona, para poder forzar al "usuario" de que introduzca el carácter correcto utilizo el bucle "Mientras" con la condición `!=`, sin embargo el programa sigue repitiendo el bucle a pesar de que coloque la letra correcta.

```
Algoritmo Ejercicio
Escribir "Introducuzca su nombre: "
Leer nombre
Escribir "Introduzca su sexo, coloque la letra (M) o (F): "
Leer sexo

Mientras sexo != "m" o sexo != "f" Hacer
    Escribir "Error! No coloco el caracter indicado"
    Escribir "Introduzca su sexo, coloque la letra (M) o (F): "
    Leer sexo
Fin Mientras


Escribir "Su nombre es ", nombre, "su sexo es", sexo "
```

FinAlgoritmo

Comment: lo que pasa, es que una de las dos condiciones siempre es verdadera... o si sexo es m, entonces sexo !=f es verdadero... tenes que poner que sexo sea distinto de m Y sexo distinto de f

Comment: Oh ya! no se como olvide un detalle tan tonto jajaaj, muchas gracias por tu respuesta :)

Answer (score 0):

Debes enfocarte en la condición del bucle.
En este case `mientras sexo!='m' o sexo !='f'` te va evaluar positivo en todas las circunstancias, es decir, si se asume que el usuario solo colocará `'m'` o `'f'` ( y no importa si es mayúscula o minúscula) el bucle siempre será positivo.

Comment: Debería ser mientras sexo!='m' y sexo !='f' (cambiar el o por el y)